# Laravel Passport: Is it possible to set expire_at for each access_token separately?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Laravel Passport does set expire_at for access tokens via

```
Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));

Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
```

in boot method of AuthServiceProvider

But I want to set expire_at for each access_token separately.

Is there any way to do so in Laravel Passport?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')` and update the `expires_at` yourself without Passport doing anything for you.

Just add your `->where` statements to the query builder to target the tokens you want, and update accordingly.

Comment: That could be the final solution & one extra query is needed. However, I would like to see if I can handle this inside Laravel Passport. As I explored, there's a static property `Passport::$tokensExpireAt`, which Passport uses to set `expires_at` in `oauth_access_tokens`. But this property works only inside the `boot` method of `AuthServiceProvider`

Comment: @Mehrud It's the same amount of queries; as passport will do the same thing under the hood. Further, I'm not aware of any built in Passport features that will do what you want. If you do find it, feel free to comment here for visibility.

Comment: I'm updating the same expires_at on every activity still my barear token get expired within 30 min(configured time) of login. how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add this line above your code:

```
Passport::tokensExpireIn(YOUR_CUSTOM_TIME);
```

But remember to change it back after that, because `expires_at` is a `static` variable.